# Excel. Use information from two different sources

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the assigned tax rate for each individual based on the country and annual income from picture below by referring to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qi2G.png).

Thank you!

[image]

=IF(OR(G6=0,G6=-1),0,INDEX(INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A7,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A7,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A7)-1),MATCH(J7,INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A7,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A7,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A7)-1),1)))

Comment: I really hope that's dummy data - if not, take a moment to go delete it and put up dummy data instead.

Comment: @user1274820 hi, what is dummy data?

Comment: @user1274820 hi, actually this is a fake name and is from some exercise, do you know how to solve the question? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

- both worksheets start in column A
- row 1 has column headings
- formula starts in row 2 on People sheet
- data in the TaxRates sheet is sorted ascending by country and then ascending by lower income
- you may want to add a row for 0 to first lower bound for each country.

Read the formula from inside out. It first establishes a lookup range that goes from the first occurrence of the given country to the last row with the given country, then does an approximate match on the lower bound income for these rows.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A2,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A2,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A2)-1),MATCH(I2,INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A2,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A2,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A2)-1),1))
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried and read your solution. But I am not sure why some cells are still #N/A, I have attached pictures 3 & 4 for your reference. Thank you!

Comment: It calculates fine for me. The error means the data can't be found. All of your Germany records produce the error, so there is something wrong with the text "Germany" in one of the sheets. Check for trailing blanks.

Comment: I have slightly changed my excelsheet by adding a column of employed,but I am not sure why after adding, the code is not working. Thank you. Picture above shows my current sheet and above has my amended code. and if it is unemployed, then the person has no income,thus no tax rate

Comment: You changed the screenshot and the premises of the question. I answered the first version of your question. Thank you for accepting that answer. If you now have a different question, please click the "Ask Question" button. Post a link to the new question here if you want. At first glance I don't see why you want to use the income from row 7 to get the tax rate for row 6.